Symfony Form manually submit
I have a Symfony form for editing data. This data may not be stored valid. However, I am trying to show validation errors when displaying the form.
A simple way to achieve this is to manually submit the form:
if (!$form->isSubmitted() && $entity->getId()) {
    $form->submit([], false);
}

But if I define the constraint like this:
$builder->add('test', TextType::class, [
    'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
]);

It doesn't work! No errors displayed.
If I define a constraint on the model (entity), it works:
#[Assert\NotBlank]
protected ?string $test = null;

I have to define constraints directly in the form (I don't have any model because it is a dynamically generated form - according to JSON Schema).
Can you advise me how to achieve this?

I'm not sure about this but have you tried adding a 'required' => true in your builder before defining your constraint ?
It seems to be how they do it in the documentation. https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html
Altough it should be implicitly true you can try it.
